# What is connection in mongo db atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, connection, application-pool

What is a connection to mongo db atlas exactly? 
Is 1 connection one find? 
Is 1 connection this: "MongoClient.connect" ?
Is 1 connection a active user using the "MongoClient.connect" ?

The M0 have a max connections at 100 so i need to know what counts as a connection so i can avoid hitting the max connections.

I don't find what a connection actually is, it would be weird if 1 connection is one user that is active and uses the app.

The problem is that i don't find a clear explanation on what a connection is

Comment: A connection in Atlas is 1 TCP connection at the instance level.  From the client side you can use netstat or the equivalent to see how many connections you have open from that host.

Comment: @Joe okey and when does that happen?
At this? "MongoClient.connect"

Comment: I suppose that depends on the driver and application code. You might want to check out the [specifications](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/specs/#mongodb-drivers-specs), such as [server discovery and monitoring](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring-summary.rst), and the documentation for the version of the driver you are using.

Comment: @Joe Alright. But just so i understand correctly, the connections have nothing to do with how many requests i get? If i have 100 users signing up at the same time VS 1 user signing up, does the connections differ?

Comment: If you have a single application server handling these signups, you can decide whether your code opens a new connection for each or uses a pool of connections.  You can further limit the connection pool so the number of connections is restricted.